# How to add loop in this code that outputs random json and save it in local?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, loops, dataframe

wrote a code using faker library in python that generates random json strings. how to add another loop in it  so ids will loop in ids place

```
import json 
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint

ids=(1,2,3,4,5,6)

print('{"data": [')
fake = Faker('en_US')
for _ in range(10):
    sms =  {
      "pid": "ABs-1cd",
      "body": fake.text(),
      "mime": fake.ean(),
      "hashed": fake.ean(),
      "celus": fake.ean(),
      "ids": "1", 
      "dev": "465p"
   }
    print(",")
    print(json.dumps(sms))

print('],"ids": "1"}')
```

and save the json according to user id like in case 1.json,2.json,3.json,4.json

Comment: Are you looking to generate 400 json files with random content, so that you will have 400 files called `1.json` until `400.json` ? What do you mean by "add another loop in it so ids will in ids place?" Is `ids` inside the json structure always supposed to equal "1"? or is it supposed to be a random integer? or is it supposed increase from 1 to 400?

Comment: edited. need single file for ids 1 where it has 10 json lines and same for other in ids. here  ids=(1,2,3,4,5,6) so need 6 files naming 1.json ...... 6.json with  each contaning 10 json flines

Comment: What is a `json` line? Can you provide an example of that! Also You are looping 400 times, but you want 10 lines per id, not sure how to correlate both?

Comment: edited pl check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
ids= (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

fake = Faker('en_US')

for ind in ids:
    cont = []
    for idx in range(10):
        sms =  {
            "pid": "ABs-1cd",
            "body": fake.text(),
            "mime": fake.ean(),
            "hashed": fake.ean(),
            "celus": fake.ean(),
            "ids": ind, 
            "dev": "465p"
        }
        cont.append(sms)

    f_name = '{}.json'.format(ind)
    with open(f_name, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(cont, fp, indent=4)
        print('saved {}'.format(f_name))
```

The outer loop iterates over the numbers 1 until 6, where each outer-loop iteration generates `<id_number>.json`. The inner-loop creates 10 python dictionaries and saves them in a list called `cont`, which is emptied at the beginning of the outer loop.

Comment: can i use strings in ids ?

Comment: why don't you try it out and see if it works. i don't see a reason why it would change anything here

Comment: if i mix both strings and ints and give this  ('486saf867641')  it is taking every digit as a separate digit.

Comment: The outer loop iterates over `ids`. That means that if `ids` is a list or a tuple, it will iterate over the values. If, however, you define `ids` as a single string, like `ids = '486saf867641'`, then the outer loop will take the string character for character.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, instead of the two `print` statement, you can append all dictionaries to a list, and then create your overall dictionary,

Also you can add another outer loop which loops through the indexes and picks id accordingly

```
import json 
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint

ids=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

data = {}
li = []

fake = Faker('en_US')
for idx in range(400):
    #Loop through id in ids
    id = ids[int(idx%6)]
    sms =  {
      "pid": "ABs-1cd",
      "body": fake.text(),
      "mime": fake.ean(),
      "hashed": fake.ean(),
      "celus": fake.ean(),
      "ids": id,
      "dev": "465p"
   }
    li.append(sms)

data['data'] = li
print(data)
```

The output will be

```
{'data': 
[{'pid': 'ABs-1cd', 'body': 'Between voice list option have. Grow yet smile citizen. After item play food lay.\nWoman same key. Join change choice market remain rise system.\nAlong that every piece. Smile face not.', 'mime': '1654036516104', 'hashed': '2183375261370', 'celus': '3745268243000', 'ids': 1, 'dev': '465p'}, 
{'pid': 'ABs-1cd', 'body': 'Politics no exist either discuss our draw. Crime mean loss there.', 'mime': '6907925600497', 'hashed': '4357683719153', 'celus': '6068299372691', 'ids': 2, 'dev': '465p'}, 
{'pid': 'ABs-1cd', 'body': 'Four cup charge. Cold wall fight himself direction coach case. Moment beyond produce prove black action.', 'mime': '0252898756297', 'hashed': '7548395540624', 'celus': '5079227810636', 'ids': 3, 'dev': '465p'}, {'pid': 'ABs-1cd', 'body': 'Area individual side eye amount artist. Side change former during pull skin. Half worker season after message travel town thousand.\nPublic end who. Summer enter key base.', 'mime': '9405000561321', 'hashed': '1072256350153', 'celus': '1521369156270', 'ids': 4, 'dev': '465p'}, {'pid': 'ABs-1cd', 'body': 'Film wide would pressure blue. Method guess while air deep. Response court make month however.', 'mime': '8541314383028', 'hashed': '3528769482198', 'celus': '2763098895122', 'ids': 5, 'dev': '465p'}, 
{'pid': 'ABs-1cd', 'body': 'Alone response detail operation. Less show crime maybe.\nLater popular agent stage number decide. Tv soldier nation member executive wrong close. Authority true popular gun student usually plant.', 'mime': '3013043458964', 'hashed': '5340459977450', 'celus': '7274348458516', 'ids': 6, 'dev': '465p'}, 
{'pid': 'ABs-1cd', 'body': 'Note PM value stand sure only test. During seem bring situation wife.\nBreak different difficult so. Leader include per catch. Attorney base card.', 'mime': '4625296268772', 'hashed': '3945698717878', 'celus': '8227765580925', 'ids': 1, 'dev': '465p'}, ....
```